# GA4 API does not extract values (not set) from Session Campaign

Tags: python, pandas, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm having a problem extracting my data from GA4. Basically the following is happening:

I created a script in Python to extract the Events and Session Campaign data into a SQL table, using the GA4 API. The thing is, when I set my script to bring: Date, Event Name, Session Campaign, Event Count and Total Users, it doesn't bring the Event Count of the Campaigns that are `(not set)`, that is, they don't have any value, as you can see below in the printout of my SQL query:

```sql
select * from ga4_hml
where 
    sessionCampaignName = '(not set)' or
    sessionCampaignName = '(direct)' or
    sessionCampaignName = '(organic)' or
    sessionCampaignName = '(referral)';
```

[Print of Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba7Eo.png)

However, it turns out that when I do the same thing in LookerStudio, using the same dimensions and metrics, and targeting the same period, the Session Campaign values `(not set)` appear normally, as you can see in the print below:

[Print of the result in LookerStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cqYM.png)

So, I don't understand what could be happening for it not to extract the `(not set)` values, since I'm using GA4's own API to do this.

Can anyone help me, please, with what I could do or what I'm not doing to get everything completely?

In Universal Analytics, I was able to bring these values in smoothly, without any problems, but after I migrated the data extraction to GA4, because Universal Analytics stopped accounting, it started giving me a lot of problems.

The Python script I'm using to extract the data is as follows:

```py
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import (
    DateRange,
    Dimension,
    Metric,
    RunReportRequest,
)
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# ----- Date ----------

data_hoje = datetime.now()
data_7_dias_atras = data_hoje - timedelta(days=8)
data_anterior = data_hoje - timedelta(days=1)
data_anterior_final = data_anterior.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# ------- GA4Connector ----------

class GA4Connector:
    def __init__(self, property_id):
        self.client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
        self.property_id = property_id
        
    def fetch_data(self, start_date, end_date):
        dimensions = [
            Dimension(name="date"),
            Dimension(name="eventName"),
            Dimension(name="sessionCampaignName"),
        ]
        metrics = [
            Metric(name="eventCount"),
            Metric(name="totalUsers"),
        ]
        date_range = DateRange(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
        response = self.client.run_report(
            RunReportRequest(
                property=f"properties/{self.property_id}",
                dimensions=dimensions,
                metrics=metrics,
                date_ranges=[date_range],
            )
        )
        return response
            
# ---------- DB connection ------------

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "G:\\Meu Drive\\DEV\\API\\archive-390417-079519729b16.json"

property_id = "XXXXXXXXX"
user_sqlserver = 'XX'
senha_sqlserver = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
host_sqlserver = 'XXXXXXXXX'
bd_sqlserver = 'XXXXXXXX'
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=' + host_sqlserver + ';'
    r'DATABASE=' + bd_sqlserver + ';'
    r'UID=' + user_sqlserver + ';'
    r'PWD=' + senha_sqlserver + ';'
)

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + user_sqlserver + ':' + senha_sqlserver + '@' + host_sqlserver + '/' + bd_sqlserver + '?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')

# ------------------ Create dataframe ------------------


start_date = '2023-08-28'
end_date = '2023-09-04'

ga4_connector = GA4Connector(property_id)
response = ga4_connector.fetch_data(start_date, end_date)

columns = [dimension.name for dimension in response.dimension_headers] + [metric.name for metric in response.metric_headers]
data = [[value.value for value in row.dimension_values] + [value.value for value in row.metric_values] for row in response.rows]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

# ------------------ Entering data ------------------

df.to_sql('ga4_hml', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=1000)
```

Comment: If you have just activated a new dimension, metric etc. you need to wait for almost 48 hours, the GA4 results are not possible to get fetched rapidly. not set means that you should wait. Plus, I would read the info related to 2 days ago as the end-date and not earlier.